# I'm looking for help with a word to describe a concise theory

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the simplest, most complete theory: concise, elegant, complete

Comment: Do you mean the simplest (etc) out of those that are on offer, or one which is a simple (etc) as can be? If the latter then, since you seem to be asking for a word for a theory that is the best in *all* regards, you might consider "ideal" or "perfect".

Comment: I don't see why 'elegant' wouldn't suffice. For example, I'd describe the theory of Evolution (which is simple, concise, and complete) as *elegant.*

Comment: The simplest theory is not necessarily the most complete one. Nor is the simplest (or the most complete) theory necessarily particularly concise or elegant. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: I agree with @rupe something which possess all positive qualities sought after in its category is  "ideal" or "perfect"

Comment: Occam's stubble? ; )

Comment: how about **concise**?  **elegant**??

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[succinct](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/succinct)**

> marked by brevity and clarity; concise

The term **[gem](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gem)** is sometimes used in a similar fashion

> a person or thing held to be a perfect example; treasure

This tends to be used when something is simple in its elegance. *Jewel* may laso be used in a similar, somewhat idiomatic manner.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

> an elegant theory

might suit you. There does not seem to be necessary to look for a more complicated word. Some [definitions](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elegant) relating to "elegant" :

> -(of theories, solutions, computer programs, etc.) gracefully concise and simple; admirably succinct.
>
> -cleverly simple; ingenious: an elegant solution to a problem.
>
> -an elegant mathematical solution--simple and precise and lucid

Comment: A more complex word might itself be inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

"Comprehensive" might be what you're looking for. Or perhaps "precise".

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you are not wanting to comment on the validity/beauty of the theory, I would suggest 'parsimonious' because it suggests smallness as a desirable attribute.